# Only last variable passed for callback function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to generate callback functions with a variable parameter for an array of buttons in Tkinter, but the problem is that only the last item is passed for all the callback functions. For instance, I have something like:

```
a = [0, 1, 2]
btn = []
for i in range(0,3):
    btn.append(Button(frame, text='something', command=lambda: funct(a[i])))
```

For each button in the btn list, the last item in the `a` list, `2`, is passed to the function `funct()`. However, what I want is `a[0]` to be passed to `funct()` for the first button, `a[1]` for the second button, and so on. How do I go about fixing this problem?

Answer (score 5):

[You're doing closures wrong.](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271/)

```
for i in range(0,3):
    btn.append(Button(frame, text='something',
      command=lambda a=a, i=i: funct(a[i])))
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you sir, you are a scholar and a gentleman.